# Django get 2nd,3rd,4th column from row. for loop

Tags: python, django

I have a row named question
It has following fields

1 `id`
2 `question`
3 `option1`
4 `option2`
5 `option3`
6 `option4`
7 `answer`

So to access option4 i would do that by `question.option4`
Now i have to display all of the 4 options

I have the following template

```
<ol>
{% for i in "xxxx" %}
<li>{{question.}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

What to write to get option1,2,3,4...
in `for loop` `question.(dont know what to write)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You expect too much from the template.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    #...
    def get_options(self):
        return [self.option1, self.option2, self.option3, self.option4]


<ol>
    {% for option in question.get_options %}
        <li>{{option}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```